# Obtain data through relation table in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this model below:

```
<?php
class Person_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function list_persons() {
        $query = $this->db->get('persons');
        return $query->result(get_class($this));
    }
}
?>
```

I can obtain an array of `Person_model` via `list_persons()`. However, in the DB schema, I have the following tables:

```
Table: persons
==============
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
first_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL

Table: rel_person_contact
=========================
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
person_id INT NOT NULL
contact_type INT NOT NULL
contact_value VARCHAR NOT NULL

Table: contact_types
====================
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
type_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
```

Sample data is as follow:

```
Table: persons
==============
id        first_name      last_name
1         John            Doe

Table: rel_person_contact
=========================
id      person_id      contact_type       contact_value
1       1              1                  johndoe@example.com
2       1              2                  +1 12345678
3       1              1                  johndoe2@example.com
4       1              4                  1 Infinite Loop, CA

Table: contact_types
====================
id     type_name
1      Email
2      Work Phone
3      Mobile Phone
4      Address
```

How can I obtain the information in `rel_person_contact` in `list_persons()` function?

It would be best if I can access the contact information like this:

```
$people = $this->person_model->list_persons();
foreach($people as $person) {
    echo 'First Name: ' . $person->first_name . '<br />';
    echo 'Emails: ' . implode(',', $person->emails) . '<br />'; // where $emails is the array containing johndoe@example.com & johndoe@example.com
    echo 'Address: ' . $person->address[0] . '<br />'; // obtaining first address
}
```

How should I modify the `list_persons()` function?

Comment: You can get the data directly by joins

Comment: Yes I know, but as I mentioned, I would like to keep the Model object structure, instead of a lot of arrays.